# Weird error when squaring numbers Python

Tags: python, r, numpy, 32-bit

As other people before me I am trying to transition from R to Python. In order to do this I am just trying to replicate simple tasks in Python just to get confident with the code.

I am trying to create just a very simple loop in Python.

Here the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mp
k=np.repeat(0, 100000, axis=0)
for x in np.arange(1,100001,1):
    k[x-1]=(x**2)
mp.pyplot.plot(k)
```

The output is this one
[image: Python Graph]

This appears really weird, I am just squaring positive numbers, why do I get negative values?

Here, the same task in R

```
k<-rep(0,100000)
for (i in 1:100000){
k[i]<-i^2
}
plot(k,type="l")
```

and the relative output
[image: R Graph]

Can someone explain me what is happening here?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue - I see the curve as per your R example. And you can create `k` easier with `k = np.arange(1,100001,1) ** 2`

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I am using spyder on an anaconda distribution

Answer (score 6):

Because of integer overflowing.

Numpy assumes that all elements in the array will be `int32` and thus some are overflowing when squared:

```
k = np.repeat(0, 100000, axis=0)
print(k.dtype)
# int32
for x in np.arange(1, 100001, 1):
    k[x - 1] = (x ** 2)
print(k[k < 0])
# [-2147479015 -2147386332 -2147293647 ...,     -537551     -352192 -166831]
```

This can be remedied by asking Numpy (nicely) to use `np.int64` as the datatype of its elements.

Your code is also not as efficient as it could be because it is using an explicit for loop (which will be executed by the Python interpreter) instead of taking advantage of Numpy's vectorization abilities which execute C code and therefore faster, and shorter (in this case a single line):

```
k = np.array(range(1, 100001), dtype=np.int64) ** 2 
# or k = np.arange(1, 100001, 1, dtype=np.int64) ** 2
mp.pyplot.plot(k)
```

generates

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how do I create float vectors?

Comment: I have a 64bit version

     Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 
     10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
     Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

     IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Comment: same graph even with this code


k=np.repeat(0, 100000, axis=0).astype(float)

for x in np.arange(1,100001,1):
    k[x-1]=(x**2)
    
mp.pyplot.plot(k)

Comment: @MarcoDeVirgilis See my updated answer for a working solution and a more efficient code as a bonus